# Ошибки при работе с консолью в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность, консоль, xna

Мне нужно, чтобы в моем приложении открывалась консоль (оно не консольное xD). Я создаю поток, который должен открыть консоль. Но после открытия, во-первых, не работают команды `Console.WriteLine()`, иногда выдает ошибку *Неверный дескриптор* на `Console.Readline()` и `Console.Clear()` (другие пока не использовал), еще при втором запуске не дает печатать текст. Помогите мне сделать так, чтобы в этом потоке консоль работала как в "Консольном приложении".
Вот код:

```
public static class CMD
    {
        private static string InPut;
        private static bool StopConsole = false;
        private static bool StartConsole = false;
        public static void Console()
        {
            StartConsole = true;
            if (AllocConsole())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Для выхода наберите exit");
                InPut = null;
                while (true)
                {                    
                    InPut = System.Console.ReadLine();
                    if (InPut == "exit")
                        break;
                    switch (InPut)
                    {
                        case "cls":
                            System.Console.Clear();
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Команда не найдена\n");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                FreeConsole();
                StopConsole = true;
            }
            StartConsole = false;
        }
        public static void SetConsole()
        {
            while (true)
                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftControl) && Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && !StartConsole)
                {
                    Thread ConsoleThread = new Thread(Console);
                    ConsoleThread.Start();
                    if (StopConsole)
                    {
                        ConsoleThread.Abort();
                        StartConsole = false;
                    }
                }
        }



        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool FreeConsole();
    }
```

Comment: @AntonKomyshan Да XNA, Monogame если быть точным. Сейчас добвлю

Comment: Покажите код как Вы вызываете метод `SetConsole()` или если где то такое ещё есть вызов метода `Console()`.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan я закидываю метод `SetConsole` в инициализаторе в отдельный поток и все он больше ни где не встречается, так же как и `Console`

Comment: @PoulShipilov: А почему бы вам не сделать ваше приложение консольным? Проблема в том, что `Console.WriteLine` не знает о консоли, которую вы подпольным образом создали через P/Invoke.

Comment: @VladD Я немного не понял вас. Мне нужно, что бы консоль открывалась в xna приложении для изменения некоторых настроек.

Comment: @ПоулШипилов: Ну, вы хотите неподдерживаемый сценарий. Консоль в неконсольном приложении не предусмотрена.

Comment: @VladD Я уже это понял. Нашел выход - взял форму и все.

Comment: @PoulShipilov: Может, запостите код формы в качестве ответа?

Comment: @ValdD да конечно, это будет разумно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вместо консоли форму со сплошным RichTextBox. Код формы:

```
public partial class UsersCommand : Form
    {
        public UsersCommand()
        {
            Game1.UsersCommandString = "";
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CommandText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Game1.UsersCommandString = CommandText.Lines.ElementAt(CommandText.Lines.Count() - 2);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                Game1.UsersCommandString = "";
            }
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            CommandText.Clear();
        }
        public void Print(string PrintText)
        {
            CommandText.AppendText(PrintText);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Пользоваться консолью в не-консольных приложениях, как ни странно, можно (ну, оставляя в стороне практическую целесообразность такой "методики"). Из какого потока обращаться к консоли совершенно неважно - все операции на консоли потокобезопасны, так как синхронизируются блокировками на глобальном объекте. Приведенный в вопросе код почти рабочий, он не учитывает только одну деталь: после уничтожения и пересоздания консоли прямым вызовом API-функций внутри класса *Console* остаются объекты *TextReader*/*TextWriter* с протухшими файловыми дескрипторами, которые необходимо пересоздать.

Нужно заменить вызов *AllocConsole* на вызов приведенного ниже метода *CreateConsole*:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern uint GetConsoleCP();

public static bool CreateConsole()
{
    bool res = AllocConsole();
    if (res == false) return false;
    uint cp = GetConsoleCP();

    //Пересоздаем stdout
    StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(
        System.Console.OpenStandardOutput(),Encoding.GetEncoding((int)cp));
    wr.AutoFlush = true;            
    System.Console.SetOut(wr);

    //Пересоздаем stdin
    TextReader read = new StreamReader(
        System.Console.OpenStandardInput(), Encoding.GetEncoding((int)cp));
    System.Console.SetIn(read);

    return true;
}
```

И поправить клавиатурный цикл (выкинуть ужасный код со *Thread.Abort* и сделать хотя бы что-то похожее на нормальную синхронизацию):

```
private static volatile bool StartConsole = false;
public static void Console()
{  
    if (CreateConsole())
    {
        /*Работа с консолью...*/
        FreeConsole();            
    }
    StartConsole = false;          
}

public static void SetConsole()
{
    while (true)
        if (/*условие входа*/ && !StartConsole)
        {
            StartConsole = true;
            Thread ConsoleThread = new Thread(Console);
            ConsoleThread.Start();                    
        } 
}
```

Тогда все заработает.

Основано на коде из данной темы: [Console error after FreeConsole is called](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38444d15-0e1d-4baa-baf7-a692f5a41074/console-error-after-freeconsole-is-called?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: У меня почему-то все равно при повторном создании консоли с дискриптором проблема. При первом все нормально, но при последующий как и было.

Comment: @PoulShipilov Да, еще нужно клавиатурный цикл переделать. Обновил ответ.

Comment: не хочет он все равно второй раз запускаться, не знаю что ему нужно

Comment: @PoulShipilov К сожалению у меня нет XNA, поэтому не могу протестировать вашу конфигурацию. Я тестирую в проекте WinForms, подменяя Keyboard.GetState()... на аналогичный вызов, тогда все работает. Видимо что-то специфичное для XNA, но в целом перезапуск консоли несколько раз несомненно возможен, нужно отлаживать конкретный код.

Comment: да вроде не должно накладываться ничего такого. Если вызавть в отдельно потоке `SetConsole` а все остальное оставить как есть, то мне выдает очень странные вещи. Я может не понимаю, но зачем там цикл и само содержание `if` не очень понимаю: если у нас условие выхода нет в первоначальном значениее то поток не запустится, если есть то консоль будет открываться всегда при закрытии

Comment: @PoulShipilov в моем коде /*условие входа*/ должно быть заменено на условие, при котором надо отобразить консоль, например что нажата определенная клавиша.

Comment: Да извиняюсь за неправильное прочтение /*условие входа*/, теперь я на 100% понимаю ваш код, но в моем проекте все проблемы, которые были, так и остались, не знаю связано ли это с движком, но работать не хочет. Я, наверное, использую вместо консоли форму, имитирующую консоль, как в своем ответе. Ну спасибо за уделенное время.